# Pybullet: limit joint torque in POSITION_COONTROL mode

Tags: python, simulator, robotics, pybullet

I'm working with a robot in Pybullet in POSITION_COONTROL mode (torque control is not convinient in my specific case). I would like to limit torque scalar on each joint. How can I achieve it without switching to torque control mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the maximum torque in position control using the `force` argument in `setJointMotorControlArray`.  See the [Quickstart Guide](https://docs.google.com/document/d/10sXEhzFRSnvFcl3XxNGhnD4N2SedqwdAvK3dsihxVUA/edit#) for more information